# Creating a table in mysql has error

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table in mysql but it throws some error i am not sure on where is the error and what is the error

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whois_redo.py", line 298, in <module>
    extractData(url,domain)
  File "whois_redo.py", line 76, in extractData
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\n            PARSE_ERROR INT(5) , \n            ORGANIZATION varchar(255) DEFAULT' at line 4")
```

Where is the error and what is the fix?

Comment: your query does not have closing tag. Is it a typo?

Comment: The `CREATE` command that you have shown is incomplete. It is missing at least the closing `)`

Comment: Is that the full SQL?  If so, there's a missing close brace at the end once the fields are declared, and also an extra close brace after creating DOMAIN

Comment: updated question @RichardSt-Cyr

Comment: edit this line to 
 "SCRAPED_PROFILE_ID int(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," and add this after the last field "PRIMARY KEY (`SCRAPED_PROFILE_ID`)"

Comment: `POSTAL_CODE int(10) DEFAULT ,` where is default value?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mysql doesn't like the `INT(5)`. Try to use `SMALLINT`.
**More info**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMAIN` column has an `)` that is not needed.

The `POSTAL_CODE` column has a default clause, but no default value.

I'm not sure that you need multiple `"` to begin and start the query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an extra parenthesis in line 4:

```
DOMAIN varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL) ,
```

Remove it and try it again.